# Which Eclipse is good for a new programmer?

Tags: java

I have downloaded eclipse-helios-pc,eclipse-jee-indigo and eclipse SDK-3.7. which version is better for a new programmer.Does it really matter?

i am watching Stanford's Programming Methodoloy lessons... would like to implement the programs... which would be best?

Comment: I can't imagine this question causing debate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally matters. You need to get [the right package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php) for what you want to do.

**Edit:** Since we're apparently recommending alternatives to Eclipse, there's also the [Community Edition of IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/), which is the greatest Java IDE known to man.

Comment: It might be good for learning on but eventually you'll have to pay for [features](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) that come with Netbeans and Eclipse for free.  Still, I have heard good things about the IDE...I just don't like to buy the cow when I get the milk for free.

Comment: @Paul, IntelliJ is the _only_ pay-for Java IDE which survives on the free market competing directly with Eclipse or Netbeans.  All others have folded or have some vendor specific code.

Comment: @Paul: Yeah, well you know [what they say about that...](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/you+get+what+you+pay+for.html) I know very few developers who have taken the time to learn IntelliJ that afterward go back to Eclipse or NetBeans, even when it means using IntelliJ CE. I do know several developers who pay for a full version of IntelliJ out of their own pockets because it's that good.

Comment: @Thor, I'm not knocking IntelliJ. I said I've heard good things about it, and besides, JetBrains gave everyone at JavaOne last year a metal water bottle.

Comment: @Paul, it just appeared you didn't know.   I have used IntelliJ a little and it didn't "click".  Perhaps I just need an experienced person to show me.

Answer (score 1):

If your new to java then it really dosn't matter if you just want to cut some code, run some examples and learn Java.

Since Eclipse is an IDE then learning Java using this as your platform will require you to learn some Eclipse. Eclipse is a quite adaptable platform with a wide variety of intermediate to advanced tool.

Are you learning Java?

Comment: yes, i am learning java.

Comment: A recommendation I would make is to use a simple text editor and the command line. It would teach you some basic. Once you have built up some confidence jump into an IDE. There are more than Eclipse out there that are just as good. Have a look around and find one that feels right.

Comment: I have learnt C/C++ moving onto Java now... I know the basics in programming but not in java

Comment: The basics I was implying was turning .java into .class and then running them. And similary turing .class into .jar and running thoses.

Comment: that i am not very sure.

Comment: brett can u explain in more detail how to turn the .java into .class..

Comment: If you are at the command line; type >javac -help

Answer (score 1):

Which is best depends on what you are trying to do.  If you are coding JSPs, servlets, EJBs etc then the Java EE edition has extra tools that will be useful.  If you are doing plain Java, a smaller distro with fewer plugins is fine.

> Does it really matter?

If you are running on a memory-poor machine, you might want to use a "smaller" Eclipse, but apart from that, and apart from the above ... it doesn't make much difference

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with a lot of new programmers, and I've found the best Eclipse for a new programmer is called [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/).

Comment: thanks, there is java se and java ee. what is the difference?

Comment: If you're just starting off get the SE edition - that's with the Java Standard Edition.  EE is Enterprise Edition...you won't need that for a while.  It comes with a couple of servers (Tomcat and Glassfish) and additional libraries for web services, e.g.  You can always add on extras to the IDE...the EE version comes more loaded from the start.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning java, consider [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) as your IDE.